# Riverpod Provider is destroyed after altering the state of a listened provider

Tags: flutter, riverpod

In a widget I'm fetching a list of orders from firebase but in the UI the customer can filtered those orders pressing as many label chips as they want, so those pressed chips makes the list to be filtered and be shown in the UI.

For this, I'm using many riverpod providers, one that is responsible for fetching the original list from the controller (and this from the repository) and another for saving the selected labels choosen from the UI and a wrapper one for saving the filtered list using the later providers, check the image for better  illustration.

I've spend many hours trying get the filtered list when selectiong the tags in the UI and nothing have worked. I going crazy with this situation  ,

filteredRecords.dart provider in charge of fetching the data

```
@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)
FutureOr<List<Records>> recordListFiltered(RecordListFilteredRef ref) async {
  print('init: recordListFiltered');
  //lista de todos los records
  final recordsList = await ref.watch(cajaControllerProvider.future);
  //set de etiquetas seleccionadas
  final selectedEtiquetas = ref.watch(etiquetaSelecProvider);

  print('la varibale de etiquetas del provider: $selectedEtiquetas');

  ref.onAddListener(() => print('onAddListener: recordListFiltered'));
  ref.onRemoveListener(() => print('onRemoveListener: recordListFiltered'));
  ref.onDispose(() => print('dispose: recordListFiltered'));
  ref.onCancel(() => print('onCancel: recordListFiltered'));

  final List<Records> updatedList = recordsList.where((element) => !selectedEtiquetas.contains(element)).toList();
  return updatedList;

}
```

etiqueta_selec.dart provider in charge of storing the selected tags from the UI

```
import 'package:riverpod_annotation/riverpod_annotation.dart';
import '../../../../models/etiquetas_model.dart';

part 'etiqueta_selec.g.dart';

@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)
class EtiquetaSelec extends _$EtiquetaSelec {

  @override
  Set<Etiqueta> build() {
    ref.onAddListener(() {
      print('EtiquetaSelecProvider: onAddListener');
    });
    return {};
  }

  void addEtiquetaSelec(Etiqueta etiqueta) {
    print('se ejecuta el método addEtiquetaSelec');

    print('el state 0 del provider de etiquetas seleccionadas es: ${state.toString()}');
    state = { ...state, etiqueta};
    print('el state 1 del provider de etiquetas seleccionadas es: ${state.toString()}');
  }

  void deleteEtiquetaSelec(Etiqueta etiqueta) {
    state.removeWhere((element) => element.nombre == etiqueta.nombre);
    state = {...state};
  }
}
```

Chip_etiquetas.dart Widget (UI)

```
import 'package:aap_pos_minegocio/core/app_exports.dart';
import 'package:aap_pos_minegocio/core/common/providers/providers/etiqueta_selec.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

import '../../../models/etiquetas_model.dart';

class ChipEtiqueta extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  final Etiqueta etiqueta;
  final bool isFilter;
  final VoidCallback? funct;

  const ChipEtiqueta({
    required this.etiqueta,
    this.isFilter = false,
    this.funct,
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  ConsumerState<ChipEtiqueta> createState() => _ChipEtiquetaState();
}

class _ChipEtiquetaState extends ConsumerState<ChipEtiqueta> {
  Set<Etiqueta> filters = <Etiqueta>{};


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('se reconstrye el el widget');
    print('el set filters es:$filters');
    final selecEtiquetasProv = ref.read(etiquetaSelecProvider.notifier);
    //filters.contains(widget.etiqueta) == true ? selecEtiquetasProv.addEtiquetaSelec(widget.etiqueta) : null;
    return widget.isFilter
        ? FilterChip(
            label: Text(
              widget.etiqueta.nombre,
              style: Theme.of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .labelSmall!
                  .copyWith(fontSize: 10.fSize, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
            ),
            selected: filters.contains(widget.etiqueta),
            onSelected: (bool selected) {
              print('el bool es: $selected');

              if (selected) {
                selecEtiquetasProv.addEtiquetaSelec(widget.etiqueta);
                setState(() {
                  filters.add(widget.etiqueta);
                });
                //print('eo');
                print('el set filters en callback es:$filters');
                print('bool: ${filters.contains(widget.etiqueta)}');
              } else {
                /*setState(() {
                  filters.remove(widget.etiqueta);
                });*/
                selecEtiquetasProv.deleteEtiquetaSelec(widget.etiqueta);
              }
            },
            shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50))),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: -7, horizontal: 0),
            labelPadding:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5, vertical: -3),
          )
        : Chip(
            label: Text(
              widget.etiqueta.nombre,
              style: Theme.of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .labelSmall!
                  .copyWith(fontSize: 10.fSize, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
            ),
            shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50))),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: -7, horizontal: 0),
            labelPadding:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5, vertical: -3),
          );
  }
}
```

I figure a strange behavior with the **filteredRecords ** provider. When changing the state of the listened provider "etiquetaSelecProvider" the onDispose callback is called, so it seems that the provider is been destroyed at this particular moment.

I think this is causing that when pressing the chips labels in the UI the orders list are not acctually filtered. Can someone help me, I'm trying to filter the orders list but somehow the riverpod providers are not working, please!!

Comment: `ref.dispose` is different with the old `dispose` method, so that behavior is expected. See [Old dispose vs ref.onDispose](https://riverpod.dev/docs/migration/from_state_notifier#old-dispose-vs-refondispose)

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```dart
final List<Records> updatedList = recordsList.where((element) => !selectedEtiquetas.contains(element)).toList();
```

The problem is that you're testing if `selectedEtiquetas`, which is a `Set<Etiqueta>`, contains `element`, which is a `Records`. Unless `Records` is extended from `Etiqueta`, this check will never returns `true`.

---

About `ref.onDispose`:

It is used to register a callback that fires before its *internal state* rebuilds. So the behavior is expected. See: [Old dispose vs ref.onDispose](https://riverpod.dev/docs/migration/from_state_notifier#old-dispose-vs-refondispose)